# Kubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, startup-applications

Am new to Kubuntu. I would like to install it(12.04.4) on my homePC.
I've got the software. Is there any installation guide?

Also, to download repositories/packages for installing applications, Is there any way to make it offline? I mean download packages at some place, copying those files to homePC and using commands to install them?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the link:- [Installation Reference][1]

[1]: http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Kubuntu_Precise_Installation in order to install Kubuntu.

And you can create an offline repo as mentioned in:- [Offline Repo][1]

[1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository and make use of apt-get or you can use apt-offline (which can be used to install packages downloaded on a machine which has network)

Comment: I want to add that the offline repository is not something you generally want to do as beginner. The way software is installed in Linux distributions differs heavily from how other operating systems go about doing things. If you're not sure what you're doing, you should stick to downloading and installing software on the same computer. I can understand why that might be frustrating, but it's better than ruining your entire package manager.